# Asymptotics for partitions of $n$ with largest part at most $k$ (or into at most $k$ parts)

Tags: asymptotics, integer-partitions

Let $\bar p_k(n)$ be the number of partitions of $n$ with largest part at most $k$ (equivalently, into at most $k$ parts). Is there an elementary formula for the asymptotic behavior of $\bar p_k(n)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ that still involves $k$ in a nontrivial way?

I would also like to know of any references that discuss the numbers $\bar p_k(n)$. Browsing Stanley v.1 isn't much help, though it's possible that I am unaware of a section in the later parts or in v.2.

Comment: Very useful paper, though this only gives a good *approximation* to the number of partitions of n
into exactly k parts each no larger than N,
due to Ratsaby (App. Analysis and Discrete M. 2008): 
http://www.doiserbia.nb.rs/img/doi/1452-8630/2008/1452-86300802222R.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number of compositions of $n$ into $k$ non-negative parts is ${n+k-1 \choose n}$.    If $n \gg k^2$ then these parts are usually all different, and if so we could divide the number of compositions by $k!$ to get partitions, so the number of partitions of $n$ with at most $k$ parts is greater than but asymptotic to $$\dfrac{n+k-1 \choose n}{k!} = \dfrac{(n+k-1)!}{n! \; (k-1)! \; k!} $$

For large $n$ and small $k$, this is clearly much the same as Gerry Myerson's answer.  For example, the number of partitions of 10,000 with largest part at most 10 (equivalently, into at most 10  parts), [this Java applet](http://www.se16.info/js/partitions.htm) gives 778,400,276,435,728,381,405,745 as the true value, i.e. about $7.78\times 10^{23}$ while Gerry's expression gives about $7.59\times 10^{23}$ and mine gives about $7.63\times 10^{23}$.

Comment: "The number of compositions of $n$ into $k$ non-negative parts is $\binom{n+k-1}{n}$." Why?

Comment: A [stars and bars method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) works well - theorem two and proof of the Wikipedia article

Answer (score 6):

The number of partitions of $n$ with largest part at most $k$ is asymptotic, as $n\to\infty$, to $$\frac{n^{k-1}}{(k-1)!k!}$$ This is a special case of a formula of Sylvester. Sylvester's theorem appears, with proof, as Theorem 4.2.1 in J L Ramirez Alfonsin, The Diophantine Frobenius Problem. My guess is that the special case goes back earlier, maybe even to Euler.

Answer (score 2):

Very useful paper, though this only gives a good *approximation* to the number of partitions of n
into exactly k parts each no larger than N
due to Ratsaby (App. Analysis and Discrete M. 2008):

http://www.doiserbia.nb.rs/img/doi/1452-8630/2008/1452-86300802222R.pdf