# Combinatorics: how many non-negative integers solutions are there for $x_1+2x_2+3x_3+...+nx_n=n$?

Tags: combinatorics

How many non-negative integers solutions are there for $x_1+2x_2+3x_3+...+nx_n=n$? (n is a non-negative integer parameter).

I can solve it with n sums one inside the other, but it isn't so nice as a final answer.

Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot better reaction if you post your solution, even if it isn't very nice.

Comment: @AnuragA In the question you post there is no answer to this question. Maybe the solution is on OEIS?

Comment: @AnuragA Interestingly enough, it seems one can give an a lot better answer to this question than to the more general one (the solution is the number of partitions of $n$)

Comment: @Crostul The coefficient of $x^n$ in $\prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{1-x^{i}}$ is a perfectly reasonable answer unless you really want a closed form. In addition if you are fine with the asymptotics, as it seems the poster of AnuragA's post was, one can be adapted from here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32677/asymptotics-for-partitions-of-n-with-largest-part-at-most-k-or-into-at-most

Comment: Also [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2902125/how-many-non-negative-integer-solutions-are-there-to-sum-i-1m-ia-i-n/)